# Отправка SMS посредством post php

Tags: php, post, api, sms

Всем привет. Есть сервис по отправке SMS и соответственно API к нему.
Для отправки sms нужно отправить POST запрос по ссылке.
Расшифровка api

```
https://xxx.net/rest/v2/Sms/Send?  
Login=<Логин>&
Password=<Пароль>&
SourceAddress=<Адрес отправителя>&  
DestinationAddress=<Номер получателя>&  
Data=<Текст сообщения>&  
Validity=<Время жизни сообщения>
```

Ссылка должна иметь вид

```
https://xxx.net/rest/v2/Sms/Send?Login=test_login&Password=test123&SourceAddress= TESTSMS&DestinationAddress=70000000000&Data=test&Validaty=0
```

Каким образом мне передать подобный запрос посредством PHP? Есть какие нибудь примеры?

```
$phonetosendsms=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'phone', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$phonefiltered = preg_replace('![^0-9]+!', '', $phonetosendsms);
$rabdom4charter= rand(1000, 9999);
$sendsmsset='https://xxx.net/rest/v2/Sms/Send?Login=TEST'.'&Password=TEST'.'&SourceAddress=TEST'.'&DestinationAddress='.$phonefiltered.'&Data='.'Proverochniy cod:'.$rabdom4charter.'&Validaty=0';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sendsmsset);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Не рабочий пример

Comment: как вариант, [используйте curl](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-exec.php)

Comment: `$phonetosendsms=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'phone', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$phonefiltered = preg_replace('![^0-9]+!', '', $phonetosendsms);
$rabdom4charter= rand(1000, 9999);
$sendsmsset='https://xxx.net/rest/v2/Sms/Send?Login=TEST'.'&Password=TEST'.'&SourceAddress=TEST'.'&DestinationAddress='.$phonefiltered.'&Data='.'Proverochniy cod:'.$rabdom4charter.'&Validaty=0';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sendsmsset);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);`  Не работает.

Comment: исправил заголовок - "посредством" (с помощью php) и "по средствам" (отправить смс по разнообразным средствам языка php), в следующий раз заминусую.

Comment: а причем здесь POST, если приведён явный GET. Непонятно

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
if (isset($_GET['send'])) {
    file_get_contents('https://xxx.net/rest/v2/Sms/Send?'.http_build_query($_POST));
}
?>
<form action="?send">
    <label><div>Логин:</div>
        <input type="text" name="Login">
    </label>
    <label><div>Пароль:</div>
        <input type="password" name="Password">
    </label>
    <label><div>Адрес отправителя:</div>
        <input type="text" name="SourceAddress">
    </label>
    <label><div>Номер получателя:</div>
        <input type="text" name="DestinationAddress">
    </label>
    <label><div>Текст сообщения:</div>
        <input type="text" name="Data">
    </label>
    <label><div>Время жизни сообщения:</div>
        <input type="text" name="Validity">
    </label>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```